# Searching Multiple Excel file using VBA with multiple search variable and output to one sheet/CSV

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to modify this code, to search multiple values, from a folder containing multiple excel files, and output it to a sheet or a CSV.

The code is able to search through multiple excel sheet and output the value but the problem is that it only outputs the first search value "**search_a**".

The code searches a folder for the value and puts it in a new sheet.

It gives the search results for search_a but not for the others search_b, search_c..... all the search result should be in one sheet.

I know i am making some simple mistake but i am unable to identify it.

I also tried to import the search values from a .txt file list but that did not work.

```
Sub SearchFolders()
    Dim xFso As Object
    Dim xFld As Object
    Dim xStrSearch As Variant
    Dim xStrPath As String
    Dim xStrFile As String
    Dim xOut As Worksheet
    Dim xWb As Workbook
    Dim xWk As Worksheet
    Dim xRow As Long
    Dim xFound As Range
    Dim xStrAddress As String
    Dim xFileDialog As FileDialog
    Dim xUpdate As Boolean
    Dim xCount As Long
    Dim xStrS As Variant
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    Set xFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
    xFileDialog.Title = "Select a forlder"
    If xFileDialog.Show = -1 Then
        xStrPath = xFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    End If
    If xStrPath = "" Then Exit Sub


    xUpdate = Application.ScreenUpdating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set xOut = Worksheets.Add
    xRow = 1
    With xOut
        .Cells(xRow, 1) = "Workbook"
        .Cells(xRow, 2) = "Worksheet"
        .Cells(xRow, 3) = "Cell"
        .Cells(xRow, 4) = "Text in Cell"
        Set xFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set xFld = xFso.GetFolder(xStrPath)
        xStrFile = Dir(xStrPath & "\*.xls*")

        xStrSearch = Array("search_a", "search_b", "search_c", "search_d", "search_e", "search_f")
        For Each xStrS In xStrSearch

        Do While xStrFile <> ""
            Set xWb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=xStrPath & "\" & xStrFile, UpdateLinks:=0, ReadOnly:=True, AddToMRU:=False)
            For Each xWk In xWb.Worksheets
                Set xFound = xWk.UsedRange.Find(xStrSearch)
                If Not xFound Is Nothing Then
                    xStrAddress = xFound.Address
                End If
                Do
                    If xFound Is Nothing Then
                        Exit Do
                    Else
                        xCount = xCount + 1
                        xRow = xRow + 1
                        .Cells(xRow, 1) = xWb.Name
                        .Cells(xRow, 2) = xWk.Name
                        .Cells(xRow, 3) = xFound.Address
                        .Cells(xRow, 4) = xFound.Value
                    End If
                    Set xFound = xWk.Cells.FindNext(After:=xFound)
                Loop While xStrAddress <> xFound.Address
            Next
            xWb.Close (False)
            xStrFile = Dir
        Loop
        Next
        .Columns("A:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With

ExitHandler:
    Set xOut = Nothing
    Set xWk = Nothing
    Set xWb = Nothing
    Set xFld = Nothing
    Set xFso = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = xUpdate
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation
    Resume ExitHandler

End Sub
```

I want the search result for all the search values in one sheet or csv.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't test my code fully, but from the little testing I did do, it seemed to work:

[image: Output]

```
Option Explicit

Private Function GetFolderPath(ByRef folderPathSelected As String) As Boolean
    Dim xFileDialog As FileDialog
    Set xFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    xFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
    xFileDialog.Title = "Select a folder"
    If xFileDialog.Show = -1 Then
        folderPathSelected = xFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
        GetFolderPath = True
    End If
End Function

Private Function GetAllExcelFilesInFolder(ByVal someFolderPath As String, Optional ByVal dirCriteria As String = "*.xls*") As Collection
     ' Could probably use FileSystemObject instead for this.
     Dim outputCollection As Collection
     Set outputCollection = New Collection

     If Right$(someFolderPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        someFolderPath = someFolderPath & "\"
     End If

     Dim Filename As String
     Filename = Dir$(someFolderPath & dirCriteria)

     Do Until Len(Filename) = 0
        outputCollection.Add someFolderPath & Filename
        Filename = Dir$()
     Loop

     Set GetAllExcelFilesInFolder = outputCollection
End Function

Private Function MaybeUnion(ByVal firstRange As Range, ByVal secondRange As Range) As Range
    ' Assumes firstRange is good (and doesn't need checking).
    If Not (secondRange Is Nothing) Then
        Set MaybeUnion = Union(firstRange, secondRange)
    Else
        Set MaybeUnion = firstRange
    End If
End Function

Private Function FindAllInWorkbook(ByVal someWorkbook As Workbook, _
                                    ByVal What As String, _
                                    Optional ByVal LookIn As XlFindLookIn = xlValues, _
                                    Optional ByVal LookAt As XlLookAt = xlWhole, _
                                    Optional SearchOrder As XlSearchOrder = xlByRows, _
                                    Optional SearchDirection As XlSearchDirection = xlNext, _
                                    Optional ByVal MatchCase As Boolean = False) As Range
    Dim outputRange As Range

    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    For Each targetSheet In someWorkbook.Worksheets
        Dim cellFound As Range
        Set cellFound = targetSheet.Cells.Find(What, , LookIn, LookAt, LookAt, SearchOrder, SearchDirection, MatchCase)

        If Not (cellFound Is Nothing) Then
            Dim addressOfFirstMatch As String
            addressOfFirstMatch = cellFound.Address
            Do
                Set outputRange = MaybeUnion(cellFound, outputRange)
                Set cellFound = targetSheet.Cells.FindNext(After:=cellFound)
            Loop Until cellFound.Address = addressOfFirstMatch
        End If
    Next targetSheet
    Set FindAllInWorkbook = outputRange
End Function

Private Sub FindStringsInWorkbooks()
    Dim folderPath As String
    If Not GetFolderPath(folderPath) Then Exit Sub

    Dim filePathsToProcess As Collection
    Set filePathsToProcess = GetAllExcelFilesInFolder(folderPath)

    Dim stringsToSearchFor As Variant
    stringsToSearchFor = Array("search_a", "search_b", "search_c", "search_d", "search_e", "search_f")

    Dim outputSheet As Worksheet
    Set outputSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    outputSheet.Range("A1:D1") = Array("Workbook", "Worksheet", "Cell", "Text in Cell")

    Dim outputRowIndex As Long
    outputRowIndex = 1 ' Skip header row

    Dim filePath As Variant
    For Each filePath In filePathsToProcess
        Dim targetBook As Workbook
        Set targetBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=filePath, UpdateLinks:=0, ReadOnly:=True, AddToMRU:=False)

        Dim stringToFind As Variant
        For Each stringToFind In stringsToSearchFor
            Dim cellsFound As Range
            Set cellsFound = FindAllInWorkbook(targetBook, stringToFind, xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows, xlNext, False)
            If Not (cellsFound Is Nothing) Then
                Dim cell As Range
                For Each cell In cellsFound
                    outputRowIndex = outputRowIndex + 1
                    With outputSheet
                        .Cells(outputRowIndex, "A") = targetBook.Name
                        .Cells(outputRowIndex, "B") = cell.Parent.Name
                        .Cells(outputRowIndex, "C") = cell.Address
                        .Cells(outputRowIndex, "D") = cell.Value
                    End With
                Next cell
            Else
                Debug.Print "No results found for '" & stringToFind & "' in workbook '" & targetBook.Name & "'."
            End If
        Next stringToFind
        targetBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Next filePath
End Sub
```

If wanted:

- It's good to take advantage of functions/procedures in your code, so that the code is a bit easier to read.
- Since you aren't making changes to the workbook/worksheets inside the loop, it should be okay for you to return all matches first and then process them later altogether (rather than processing them as you find them).
- I think it makes sense to have the workbook loop on the outside, and the search term loop on the inside. Otherwise, you will be opening and closing the same workbook `N` times (where `N` is how ever many search terms you have). However, this does mean that the order of the output/results will be different.
- You may need to re-implement formatting (e.g. auto-fit column widths and so on) -- and toggle `Application.ScreenUpdating` as necessary.